# postgresql query a json col with array of objects

Tags: json, postgresql, sum

in my table there is one cell that contains a json- array of objects, one of the properties  from the object is an number(that i need to extract), the others are strings.

```
[{"a":"bla","b":"5k", "c":"foo"}, {"a":"bla","b":"9k", "c":"baz"}, {"a":"bla","b":"15k", "c":"foo"}]
```

^ a single json example.

```
select 
        jsonb_array_elements("jsons") ->> 'a' as a,
        jsonb_array_elements("jsons") ->> 'c' as c,

        regexp_replace(jsonb_array_elements("jsons")->> 'b', '\D','','g')::numeric as num
        
from x.y
where "some filter here"
and "condition 1"
and "condition 2"
and "condition 3"
```

this query gives me like 30 results,

the thing is, I cant find a way to sum the numbers.
even a simple sum with no conditions returns an error.

I’m new to sql and don’t really know the depths of it, so im probably  missing something  over here.

what I would like to do is something  like this

```
select 
        

 sum(
if(jsonb_array_elements("jsons") ->> 'a' = 'bla' and jsonb_array_elements("jsons") ->> 'c' = 'foo'
 then(regexp_replace(jsonb_array_elements("jsons")->> 'b', '\D','','g')::numeric)
   else(0)
  )) as sum
from x.y
where "some filter here"
and "condition 1"
and "condition 2"
and "condition 3"
```

I expect that in this case if all the jsons are the same as in the example above  I will get a result of 600 (30 *(5+15))

Comment: You might want to start by using *valid* JSON... Then [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scalar subquery:

```
select t.*, 
       (select sum(regexp_replace(item ->> 'b', '\D', '')::numeric)
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.jsons) as x(item)
        where x.item ->> 'a' = 'bla'
          and x.item ->> 'c' = 'foo') as b_sum
from the_table t
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```sql
select
  sum(regexp_replace(e.value ->> 'b', '\D', '')::numeric) 
    filter (where e.value ->> 'a' = 'bla' and e.value ->> 'c' = 'foo')
from
  test t cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.jsons) e;
```